# presentation: option screen or prepress in ps2pdf?

Tags: pdf, presentations, file-size

I'm using the *Powerdot* class to make a presentation. *Powerdot* uses *eps* pictures and thus on compiling, I'm using the normal route:

```
Latex > dvi > ps > pdf.
```

In *Ghostscript*, we have the *ps2pdf* tool. I normally use

```
-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress
```

for all usage. I read somewhere that setting the `/screen` option instead of `/prepress` creates a smaller pdf file. For the presentation that I'm working on, I see that both settings give the same file size.

In any case, what's the best option to put for a presentation?

Am I right to think that setting the option to /prepress will create a file of high resolution that will make the presentation appear very well on a projector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all options of ps2pdf  [here](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html#controls-and-features-specific-to-postscript-and-pdf-input). The `PDFsettings` part is below:

```
-dPDFSETTINGS=configuration
    Presets the "distiller parameters" to one of four predefined settings:

        * /screen selects low-resolution output similar to the Acrobat Distiller "Screen Optimized" setting.
        * /ebook selects medium-resolution output similar to the Acrobat Distiller "eBook" setting.
        * /printer selects output similar to the Acrobat Distiller "Print Optimized" setting.
        * /prepress selects output similar to Acrobat Distiller "Prepress Optimized" setting.
        * /default selects output intended to be useful across a wide variety of uses, possibly at the expense of a larger output file.
```

So in principle /screen will give the smallest output. It's already enough for a projector.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have seen this from ps2pdf.htm. So u mean that /prepress will appear better than /screen on a projector? 1 vote up.

Comment: Because the typical resolution of a projector is 1024x768, the improvement on the file quality above this level is usually meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is true:

```
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen   -- 72 dpi;

  -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook    -- 150 dpi;

  -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer  -- 300 dpi greyscale;

  -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -- 300 dpi color.
```

Correct me if I am wrong.